# Upload an image buffer with cloudinary fails with Invalid image file

Tags: node.js, file-upload, cloudinary

**SOLVED**:

I needed to add `bodyParser: false` in the api:

```js
import { yoga } from '~/shop/src/api/server';

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default yoga;
```

---

I followed [the example here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#upload_data_stream):

```js
// e.g., using the streamifier library
let streamifier = require('streamifier');
let cld_upload_stream = cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload_stream(
    {  folder: "foo" },
    function(error, result) {console.log(error, result);});
streamifier.createReadStream(req.file.buffer).pipe(cld_upload_stream);
```

Here's what I have:

```js
export function upload({ buff }) {
  return new Promise<string | null | undefined>((res, rej) => {
    console.log(stream);
    const fileStream = streamifier.createReadStream(Buffer.from(buff));
    const cl = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(
      {
        resource_type: 'image',
      },
      (error, result) => {
        if (result?.secure_url) {
          res(result?.secure_url);
        }
      }
    );
    fileStream.pipe(cl);
  });
}
```

The log on `stream`:

```bash
<Buffer ef bf bd ef bf bd ef bf bd ef bf bd 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ef bf bd ef bf bd 01 ef bf bd 49 43 43 5f 50 52 4f 46 49 4c 45 00 ... 143345 more bytes>
```

```js
console.log(file);
await upload({ buff: await file.arrayBuffer() });
```

The log on `file`:

```bash
PonyfillFile {
  blobParts: [
    <Buffer ef bf bd ef bf bd ef bf bd ef bf bd 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ef bf bd ef bf bd 01 ef bf bd 49 43 43 5f 50 52 4f 46 49 4c 45 00 ... 143345 more bytes>
  ],
  _size: null,
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  encoding: 'utf8',
  name: '364134631_307216381832243_6014366443875645446_n.jpg',
  webkitRelativePath: '',
  lastModified: 1699915030221
}
```

The request fails with this error:

```js
{ message: 'Invalid image file', name: 'Error', http_code: 400 }
```

Edit:
Looks like it comes from the file, I added:

```js
        const fileArrayBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
        await fs.promises.writeFile(
          path.join(__dirname, file.name),
          Buffer.from(fileArrayBuffer)
        );
```

File is written on the disk but I can't open it. Same for a pdf, the content is empty

I use `graphql-yoga` in `nextjs`.